# Linear gradient having different behavior [Chrome, Edge, Firefox] vs IE11

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to achieve the following UI design with CSS

[Example UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08kwu.png)

So what im doing right now is using 3 divs, 2 for the triangles on top and bottom and 1 for the actual content in the middle.

To make the triangular form i'm using linear-gradiant but the problem i'm facing is that it looks different depending on the navigator.

This is my example on Pen http://codepen.io/archer3cl/pen/ybLPgq

```
background: linear-gradient(to top right, black 49%, #FFF 51%); /*Top triangle*/
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 49%, #fff 51%); /*Bottom triangle*/
```

In Chrome, Edge and Firefox it looks like the design, but in IE11 looks diffuse. You can open the pen in either navigator to see the difference

What could be done to make all the navigators display the same style?

Comment: You could try using 50% for the color stops instead of 49 and 51.

Comment: @Quantastical I tried that but it looks pixelated on Chrome. You can change the values on my Pen to see that